# sablon gem is not supporting the html text after generate DOCX Report

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, sass

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5doY.png)

my html tags like this
and once i open docx on Microsoft Word  all the html text will show into one line
do you guys have any idea how to fix this issue on ruby on rails

once i open Docx Format should be correct form on Docx

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.